# Pylint throwing non-text encoding used in str.decode

Tags: python, pylint

I have the following line in code:

```
decoded_url = url.decode('base64')
```

when I run `pylint --py3k <path_to_file>` it throws following warning:

`non-text encoding used in str.decode (invalid-str-codec)`

I tried searching but couldn't find anything concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `.decode` to turn bytestrings that are encoded as, say, Latin-1 or Windows-1252 or UTF-8 into Unicode. That is because these codecs all have different ways of representing characters not in the ascii character set.

But base-64 is an entirely different sense of the word *encoding*. To decode a base-64 string you do this:

```
import base64
base64.b64decode(url)
```

`pylint` is just telling you that you are using `base64` in an inappropriate context.